# Problems installing GIT on Ubuntu (Jaunty) via apt-get

Tags: installation, git, ubuntu-9.04, http-status-code-404

I am trying to install **git** using `sudo apt-get install git-core`

But it fails with this error message:

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
liberror-perl git-core patch
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main git-core 1:1.6.0.4-1ubuntu2
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main patch 2.5.9-5
404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/git-core/git-core_1.6.0.4-       1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/patch/patch_2.5.9-  5_amd64.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How can I resolve these apt-get errors or install GIT using a different method.

Note: I've used apt-get to pull other things, it's just failing with git.

Comment: Jaunty is massively beyond unsupported.  The archives you once installed from are no longer there.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu ended support for Jaunty Jackalope (version 9.04) on 23 October 2010. The Ubuntu mirrors most likely no longer have the packages you're looking for.

You can find instructions on how to update an EOL Ubuntu product here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that now. I just started a position here and sortof have been just thrown all this info to the servers and saying here, fix these :P Appreciate the response.

Comment: If this is a production box, make sure you have a full backup before upgrading to the latest Ubuntu. Nothing **should** break but ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to upgrade your ubuntu, you can build git yourself. The problem with getting git from the standard package managers (and default resources) is that they lag the latest git version quite a bit in some cases.

Git is just a command without any hooks into the OS, so using and installing it outside of a package manager is just fine.

Comment: The op would probably benefit from directions on how to download and build git from source